# Obtener Items Seleccionados en selects multiple con Nebular (ANGULAR)

Tags: angular

Hola a todos quisiera saber como obtener mis opciones seleccionadas en los selects multiple, estoy ultizando nebular, es facil hacerlo con array de string, pero al momento de utilizar con objetos no logro dar como seria

Ejemplo con array de string

```
HTML
        <nb-select
          [(selected)]="pruebaSelected"
          style="width: 100%;"
          placeholder="
          '--Seleccione--'
          "
          multiple>fullWidth
          <nb-option [value]="vehiculo" *ngFor="let vehiculo of vehiculos">casa</nb-option>
        </nb-select>

.TS
  pruebaSelected= ['carro'];
  vehiculos = ['carro','moto']
```

DE ESTA MANERA OBTENDRIA ESTE RESULTADO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SIN EMBARGO QUISIERA SABER COMO SERIA CON OBJETOS, YA INTENTE DE ESTA FORMA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
TS
  pruebaSelected= [{tipo:'moto',color:'azul'}];
  vehiculos = [{tipo:'carro',color:'rojo'},{tipo:'moto',color:'azul'}];
```

RESULTADO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(NO APARECEN LOS ITEMS YA SELECCIONADOS)

LA IDEA ES MANTENER EL VALOR DEL OBJETO PARA DESPUES MANIPULARLO FACIL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione el valor en `pruebaSelected` debe estar contenido en `vehiculos`, en este caso como son objetos, no basta con que tengan las mismas propiedades sino que debe ser el mismo objeto.

```
vehiculos = [{tipo:'carro',color:'rojo'},{tipo:'moto',color:'azul'}]
pruebaSelected = this.vehiculos[0] //se guarda una referencia
```

En el ejemplo `pruebaSelected` guarda una referencia a un objeto en el arreglo `vehiculos`.